# Using GDi drawing with both 32 & 64 bit applications

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, gdi+, gdi

Can a COM 32 bit out of process server be used for GDI drawing on a 64 bit process?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. For GDI object HANDLEs and window HANDLES, it's guaranteed that only the low 32-bits will be used in 64-bit mode, so it should be safe to pass these between 32-bit and 64-bit. Of course, the COM server *must* be out of process.

Quoting from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> On 64-bit Windows, an out-of-process 32-bit COM server can communicate with a 64-bit client, and an out-of-process 64-bit COM server can communicate with a 32-bit client. Therefore, if you have a 32-bit DLL that is not COM-aware, you can wrap it in an out-of-process COM server and use COM to marshal calls to and from a 64-bit process.

Similarly, from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> 64-bit versions of Windows use 32-bit handles for interoperability. When sharing a handle between 32-bit and 64-bit applications, only the lower 32 bits are significant, so it is safe to truncate the handle (when passing it from 64-bit to 32-bit) or sign-extend the handle (when passing it from 32-bit to 64-bit). Handles that can be shared include handles to user objects such as windows (HWND), handles to GDI objects such as pens and brushes (HBRUSH and HPEN), and handles to named objects such as mutexes, semaphores, and file handles.